# Set default group to Cache in kohana 3.3

Tags: php, caching, kohana

After upgrade Kohana framework from 3.2 to 3.3, Cache ask me to put an default group to it.

**config/cache.php**

```
return array(
     'default' => array(                    // Driver group
         'driver'         => 'apc',         // using APC driver
         'default_expire' => 3600,          // life time
      ),
);
```

Before, I used to do like this without the group name:

```
Cache::instance()->set('key', 'val');
```

Now, that sends an Exception: Failed to load Kohana Cache group: file.

But, when I set the name group all woks perfect.

```
Cache::instance('default')->set('key', 'val');
```

How can I set now in 3.3 a default group without type it always whatever I want to use it?  Maybe is a new upgrade, but, I checked the new features of kohana 3.3 and I don't see any of that.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright so, here's the deal. Without the cache group supplied, it defaults to file.  So if you -dare- change that, be my guest.  But just set the static instance in `bootstrap.php`, answer at the bottom.

-- This is from the base cache class. --

```
public static $default = 'file';

public static function instance($group = NULL)
{
    // If there is no group supplied
    if ($group === NULL)
    {
        // Use the default setting
        $group = Cache::$default;
    }
```

So in your `bootstrap.php` set this, though I would name it to APC in your config:

```
Cache::$default = 'default';
```